# Is it possible to run ASP.NET MVC application on Cassini server?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ultidev-cassini

Is it possible to run ASP.NET MVC application on UltiDev Cassini webserver?

If so.. are there any drawbacks / things that I need to have in mind when building this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Yes you can. This is what I use for web development, as my OS is Windows XP Pro, and IIS 5.1 is limited to a single site on this licence.

When I use Ultidev, I turn IIS off, because I use port 80 for my main website.

When I need to debug, I select "Attach to process" (Control + Alt + P), and choose `Ultidev.exe`.

There are the usual limitations though that exist with Cassini, such as no HTTPS and the max number of concurrent users is ten (AFAIK). But then, it's obviously not meant to be a production server. :)

If you are wanting to run this as a production environment, then you should look at ponying up the cash for a server licence and use IIS.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for (Comet Way) has a product called Neokernel Web Server, (http://www.neokernel.com) which is a commercial product for C# that lets you embed an SSL secured, scalable ASP.NET web server in your application. It's a commercial product but a free evaluation license is available.